# Redraw custom column in jQueryUI.datepicker after update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendar

I'm trying to customize jQueryUI's datepicker to do some cool things for my client, but I'm stuck.  I've added a custom column to the calendar to display the Rate for the rental for each week.  Sadly, jQueryUI's calendar works by redrawing itself on every click, so my custom column gets removed, and obviously this would also happen if they change the month.

I'm looking for best practice to detect if my column has disappeared and redraw it.  I wish jQueryUI.datepicker fired some sort of "done" event when it's finished drawing, but that doesn't happen.  And all of it's hooks are before drawing the calendar.  Any help is appreciated.

The code

```
/**
 * A Wrapper for jQueryUI.datepicker.
 */

(function( factory ){
    factory( jQuery );
}( function( $ ){

    function MpCalendar(options) {
        options = options || {}

        this._curInst = null;
        this._defaults = {
            highlightDateCSS: "mpcalendar-highlight",
            weeklyRateCSS: "mpcalendar-weekly-rate",
            weeklyRateHeading: "Rate"
        };

        this.settings = $.extend({}, this._defaults, options);
    };

    $.extend(MpCalendar.prototype , {
        /* Create a new instance of the object. */
        _newInst: function(target) {
            return {
                element: target,
                blockDates: {},
                weeklyRates: [],
                input1: [],
                input2: []
            };
        },

        /* Retrieve a previous instance of the object. */
        _getInst: function(target) {
            try {
                return $.data(target, "mpcalendar");
            } catch(e) {
                throw "Missing instance for this MpCalendar.";
            }
        },

        /* Attach the calendar to the target element */
        _attachMpCalendar: function(target, settings) {
            //Check that we were given a div or span.  We're only making inline calendars.
            var nodeName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if(nodeName !== ("div" || "span"))
                throw new Error('Target must be a div or span got "'+nodeName+'" instead.');

            var self = this;

            var inst = this._newInst($(target));
            inst.settings = $.extend({}, settings || {}, {
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    return self._beforeShowDay(inst, date);
                },
                onSelect: function(date, datepicker) {
                    return self._onSelect(inst, date, datepicker);
                }
            });

            //Make sure showWeek is true.
            inst.settings.showWeek = true;

            //Make sure we have inputs to use.
            inst.input1 = $(inst.element.data('mpinput1'));
            if(!inst.input1.length)
                throw new Error('Could not find mpinput1.');

            inst.input2 = $(inst.element.data('mpinput2'));
            if(!inst.input2.length)
                throw new Error('Could not find mpinput2.');

            //Initiate block dates found in the settings.
            if(typeof inst.settings.blockDates === "object")
                this._setBlockDates(inst, inst.settings.blockDates);

            //Initiat weekly rates found in the settings.
            if(typeof inst.settings.weeklyRates === "object")
                this._setWeeklyRates(inst, inst.settings.weeklyRates);

            //Initiate datepicker.
            inst.element.datepicker(inst.settings);

            //Draw extra rates column.
            this._attachRates(inst);

            //Store our instance.
            $.data(target, "mpcalendar", inst);
        },

        /* Set block dates with the given list of dates */
        _setBlockDatesMpCalendar: function(target, dates) {
            if(typeof dates !== "object")
                throw new Error('Expected dates to be an "object" got "' + typeof dates + '" instead.');

            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            this._setBlockDates(inst, dates);
        },

        /* Add a given date to the block list */
        _addBlockDateMpCalendar: function(target, date, status) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            this._addBlockDate(inst, date, status);
        },

        /* Remove a given date from the block list */
        _removeBlockDateMpCalendar: function(target, date) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            this._removeBlockDate(inst, date);
        },

        /* Set Weekly Rates with the given list of rates */
        _setWeeklyRatesMpCalendar: function(target, rates) {
            if(!(Array.isArray(rates)))
                throw new Error('Expected rates to be an "array" got "' + typeof rates + '" instead.');

            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            this._setWeeklyRates(inst, rates);
        },

        /* Set the Rate for a single Week */
        _setWeeklyRateMpCalendar: function(target, week, rate) {
            if(typeof week !== "number")
                week = parseInt(week);

            if(typeof rate !== "number")
                rate = parseFloat(rate);

            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            this._setWeeklyRate(inst, week, rate);
        },

        /**
         * Return an array of Date objects contianing the dates selected on the calendar.
         * 
         * @param {object} target
         * @returns {Array}
         */
        _getSelectedDatesMpCalendar: function(target) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            return this._getSelectedDates(inst);
        },

        /**
         * Return the CSS Class used for the specified date or false if the date is not blocked.
         * 
         * @param {object} target
         * @param {Date} date
         * @returns {string}
         */
        _isBlockedDateMpCalendar: function(target, date) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);

            return this._isBlockedDate(inst, date);
        },

        /* Attach our custom weekly rates column */
        _attachRates: function(inst) {
            var self = this;

            //Attach header and empty rates.
            var heading = $('<th>'+ this.settings.weeklyRateHeading +'</th>');
            var tdata = $('<td class="'+this.settings.weeklyRateCSS+'"></td>');
            inst.element.find('.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr').append(heading);
            inst.element.find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr').append(tdata);

            inst.element.find('td.ui-datepicker-week-col').each(function(){
                var week = parseInt($(this).text());
                var rate = inst.weeklyRates[week] || "Test";

                $(this).closest('tr').find('.'+ self.settings.weeklyRateCSS).html(rate);
            });
        },

        _isBlockedDate: function(inst, date) {
            if(!(date instanceof Date))
                throw new Error('Expected date to be instance of Date.');

            try {
                var vacancyStatus = inst.blockDates[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()] || false;

                return vacancyStatus;
            } catch(e) {

            }

            return false;
        },

        _getSelectedDates: function(inst) {
            var dates = [];

            try {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, inst.input1.val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, inst.input2.val());

                if((date1 || date2) === null)
                    return dates;

                while(date1 <= date2) {
                    dates.push(new Date(date1));
                    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                }
            } catch(e) {
                //Guess we don't have any dates.
            }

            return dates;
        },

        _setBlockDates: function(inst, dates) {
            inst.blockDates = {};

            for(var date in dates) {
                if(typeof dates[date] !== 'string')
                    continue;

                this._addBlockDate(inst, date, dates[date]);
            }
        },

        _setWeeklyRates: function(inst, rates) {
            inst.weeklyRates = [];

            for(var week in rates) {
                var rate = rates[week];

                if(typeof week !== 'number')
                    week = parseInt(week);

                if(typeof rate !== 'number')
                    rate = parseFloat(rate);

                this._setWeeklyRate(inst, week, rate);
            }
        },

        _removeBlockDate: function(inst, date) {
            try {
                var datetime = new Date(date);
                var day = datetime.getDate();
                var month = datetime.getMonth();
                var year = datetime.getFullYear();

                delete inst.blockDates[year][month][day];
            } catch(e) {
                //The date probably never existed any way.
            }
        },

        _addBlockDate: function(inst, date, status) {
            if(typeof status !== "string")
                throw new Error('Expected class name to be typeof "string" got "' + typeof status + '".');

            try {
                var datetime = new Date(date);

                var day = datetime.getDate();
                var month = datetime.getMonth();
                var year = datetime.getFullYear();

                if(typeof inst.blockDates[year] !== "object")
                    inst.blockDates[year] = {};

                if(typeof inst.blockDates[year][month] !== "object")
                    inst.blockDates[year][month] = {};

                inst.blockDates[year][month][day] = status;
            } catch(e) {
                throw new Error('Error adding block date: "' + e.message + '".');
            }
        },

        _setWeeklyRate: function(inst, week, rate) {
            inst.weeklyRates[week] = rate;
        },

        /* Function attached to datepicker's beforeShowDay, handles showing blocked dates and range selection */
        _beforeShowDay: function(inst, date) {
            var cssClasses = [];

            try {
                var vacancyStatus = inst.blockDates[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()];

                if(vacancyStatus !== undefined)
                    cssClasses.push(vacancyStatus);
            } catch(e) {
                //There is no blockDate set.
            }

            try {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, inst.input1.val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, inst.input2.val());

                var highlight = ((date.getTime() === date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? this.settings.highlightDateCSS : '';

                cssClasses.push(highlight);
            } catch(e) {
                //Oh well.
            }

            if(cssClasses.length > 0)
                return [true, cssClasses.join(' '), null];

            return [true, '', null];
        },

        /* Function attached to datepicker's onSelect, allows for rangeselection */
        _onSelect: function(inst, dateText, datepicker) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, inst.input1.val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, inst.input2.val());
            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);


            if (!date1 || date2) {
                inst.input1.val(dateText);
                inst.input2.val("");
                inst.element.datepicker('refresh');
            } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {
                inst.input2.val( inst.input1.val() );
                inst.input1.val( dateText );
                inst.element.datepicker('refresh');
            } else {
                inst.input2.val(dateText);
                inst.element.datepicker('refresh');
            }
        },

        /* Because we are wrapping datepicker, this handles jQuery calls to internal functions for both MpCalendar and datepicker */
        _callFunction: function(target, option) {
            var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

            if(typeof this["_"+option+"MpCalendar"] === "function")
                return this["_"+option+"MpCalendar"].apply(this, [target].concat(otherArgs));

            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            inst.element.datepicker.apply(inst.element.datepicker(), [option].concat(otherArgs));
        }
    });

    //jQuery extension for using MpCalendar.
    $.fn.mpcalendar = function(options) {
        var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

        //If they are calling for one of our static methods, pass the call to MpCalendar and return the value.
        if(typeof options === "string" && (options === "isBlockedDate" || options === "getSelectedDates"))
            return $.mpcalendar["_"+options+"MpCalendar"].apply($.mpcalendar, [ this[0] ].concat(otherArgs));

        //Else, call the appropriate function and return.
        return this.each( function() {
            typeof options === "string" ?
                $.mpcalendar._callFunction.apply($.mpcalendar, [ this, options ].concat(otherArgs)) :
                $.mpcalendar._attachMpCalendar(this, options);
        });
    };

    $.mpcalendar = new MpCalendar();

    return $.mpcalendar;
}));
```

My fiddle where I've been prototyping: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/squeegy06/djdLge3p/)

I've found a few other stack questions talking about custom columns, but none so far address the problem of what to do on an update.  I don't really want to use setIntval() that could cause some weird behavior.  And I'm not sure if attaching an event on remove would work, datepicker does call `.empty()` on the containing div just before attaching the newly drawn calendar, but wouldn't that mean that my remove event would start drawing before the calendar even exists?  Or maybe not draw at all as `.empty()`

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it was me I would probably look at cloning the file for datepicker.js and overwrite it within the full jQueryUI as separate script tag. Then add some custom events in it that your code could listen for. Wouldn't prevent upgrade of the full library that way

Comment: Yeah, but where's the fun in that?  And then I've gotta maintain all of datepicker...I'm enjoying this challenge, but that might have to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works I guess.  But results in the elements "flashing" on the screen as the calendar appears before the rows.  I may be able to fix that with some CSS, but if anyone has a better idea, let me know.  In the meantime I've updated the fiddle linked in my original question.

The code

```
/* Attach our custom weekly rates column */
        _attachRates: function(inst) {
            var self = this;

            //Attach header and empty rates.
            var heading = $('<th>'+ this.settings.weeklyRateHeading +'</th>');
            var tdata = $('<td class="'+this.settings.weeklyRateCSS+'"></td>');
            inst.element.find('.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr').append(heading);
            inst.element.find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr').append(tdata);

            inst.element.find('td.ui-datepicker-week-col').each(function(){
                var week = parseInt($(this).text());
                var rate = inst.weeklyRates[week] || "Test";

                $(this).closest('tr').find('.'+ self.settings.weeklyRateCSS).html(rate);
            });

            inst.element.find('.ui-datepicker-calendar').first().on('remove', function(){
                $(this).off("remove");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    self._attachRates(inst);
                }, 1);
            });
        },
```